# Left join, inner join, join anything?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am doing two request, to get a value. In my opinion one would be faster. I think the best way is to use join. This is my code:

```
$uid = db_query("SELECT uid FROM TABLE1 WHERE mail = '{$account->mail}' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($uid);
$uid = $row[0];


$brief = db_query("SELECT value FROM Table2 WHERE uid = '{$uid}' AND fid = '16' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($brief);
$brief = $row[0];`
```

How can I merge these two request to one?

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT value, ui
      FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
     USING (uid)
     WHERE mail = '{$account->mail}'
       AND fid = 16
     LIMIT 1
```

But your queries are weird. Is `uid` unique ? Is `fid` unique ? Otherwise, it's going to select a "random" line.

Basically, my query joins TABLE1 with Table2 using the uid column, and it only takes rows where mail = $account->mail and fid = 16. So if there are more than one row, you can't be sure which one is going to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

The query would be:

```
SELECT TABLE1.uid,TABLE2.value
FROM TABLE1,TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.mail = '{$account->mail}'
  AND TABLE2.uid = TABLE1.uid
  AND TABLE2.fid = '16'
LIMIT 1
```

Grabbing the data from the row:

```
$uid = $row[0];
$brief = $row[1];
```

Comment: This is a cartesian product. $uid variable is from the first query, I think you wanted to write `TABLE2.uid = TABLE1.uid`. But to be honest, I'm not a fan of the old syntax, the syntax with INNER JOIN (or NATURAL INNER JOIN) is much more clear.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Yes, it theoretically is a cartesian product, but doesn't `LIMIT 1` prevent that?

Comment: @thejh: It's still a cartesian product, you have no idea which row is going to be matched first. But it won't work anyway because $uid doesn't exist (as I said, it's from his first query).

Comment: Yes, $uid is a unique value. I just implemented the query from Vincent and it works. Which one is better/faster? That one form vincent or that from thejh?

Comment: @Chris : The query plan is the exact same. It's subjective, but I prefer my version (I find it more clear with an explicit INNER JOIN), but this works too.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided syntax, so I won't repeat that part. But as to what type of join to use:

To get literally what you would get with the above, you would use a `left join` with TABLE1 as the first table in the join.

In your sample, you always get `uid` and you may get `value`. A left join would give you the same result in that you would always get back a result(`uid`) from TABLE1 and the row(s) (`value`) that matched from TABLE2. Of course, that's assuming a value for `mail` was matched.

A note: As I understand its use, using `LIMIT 1` could mask an issue if you don't have a unique constraint on the mail column. If there were two rows in TABLE1 with the same mail value, you'd never know it with this query. In some cases, that may be a bug in your system.